# ¿Como invocar un servicio web publicado en un bus de servicio mediante AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, soap

Estoy trabajando con *Oracle Service Bus*, actualmente he creado unos servicios con *SOA* en *JDeveloper*, los cuales he publicado en el *bus* de servicio que ofrece *Oracle*, ahora necesito acceder a ellos desde mi aplicación móvil hecha en *PhoneGap*. ¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo? He utilizado una función en *AJAX* pero no sirve:

```
conectar = function () {
    var url = "http://10.0.0.191:7001/OSBCapled/Proxy_Services/AutenticacionWS?WSDL"
    var datos = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
        + '<soap:Header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
        + '</soap:Header>'
        + '<soapenv:Body>'
        + '<aut:requestRegistro xmlns:aut="http://www.integracion.org/autenticacion">'
        + '<aut:Email>'+$('#usuario').val()+'</aut:Email>'
        + '<aut:Clave>'+$('#clave').val()+'</aut:Clave>'
        + '</aut:requestRegistro>'
        + '</soapenv:Body>'
        + '</soapenv:Envelope>';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        data: datos,
        cache:false,
        dataType: 'text/xml',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Funciono!! " + data.responseText);
        },
        error: function (data) {
           alert("Error"):
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Puede haber varios problemas, te da algún mensaje de error si consultas la herramienta de depuración del navegador?

Comment: ¿puedes agregar los mensajes de errore que te arroja la consola de JS? La invación llega al bus? Arroja algíun error ahí? Puedes probar el servicio con soapUI u otro?

En estricto rigor, la invocación al bus, es lo mismo que a cualquier otro servicio web.

Comment: No me da ningún error, el método no devuelve nada, al parecer no realiza la conexión. Probe el mismo método de ajax con un servicio web en asp.net y si funciona perfectamente, el problema está en ese sevicio web que intento invocar hacia el OSB. Mi pregunta es si la invocación debería ser diferente o me falta algo?

Comment: Ese es el problema la invocación no llega al bus, es decir, parece que no realiza la conexión y cuando intento imprimir el error, no aparece nada

Comment: Desde JavaScript estás limitado a hacer llamadas al mismo dominio por eso funciona desde tu servicio y no desde Ajax, ahora te pregunto si el servicio que estás consultando es tuyo o de un tercero?

Comment: Pero probaste ejecutar desde soapUI o ejecutar directmante desde el browser? En caso extremo, podrias esnifear la red y ver que está pasando.

Comment: El servicio es mio, yo lo cree con SOA desde JDeveloper y lo desplegue en el OSB

Comment: Probando directamente desde la consola del OSB la invocación funciona, con soapUI también funciona, incluso creé un servicio proxy en java que invoca dichos servicios y funciona, el problema es en ajax que no me permite realizar la conexión, no devuelve nada, pero pasa por la función error de ajax sin retornar nada.

Comment: con la función fail pude ver el error: y dice "Not connect: Verify Network", lo que habia dicho anteriormente no se conecta, pero el servidor está arriba y OSB funcionando. No se que puede estar mal en el ajax. No se si es la URL, a algún parametro que me falta colocar en el método

Comment: Ok, y la url está en el mismo dominio que desde donde querés consumirlo? tanto el dominio como el puerto deben ser iguales si no tenés CORS habilitado.

Comment: El dominio si es el mismo, pero el puerto no lo es, como hago para habilitar CORS?

Comment: Actualmente el error que imprime desde la función fail de ajax es "Not connect: Verify Network"

Comment: @maryvargas aquí: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Gracias!!! Pero el servidor que uso es weblogic y allí no aparece, intentaré buscar en internet. Pero te agradecería si consigues una página que me pueda ayudar con weblogic. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Antes de habilitar CORS para estar seguro te recomiendo que probés con una extensión de Chrome que te permite "saltear" la restricción del mismo puerto / dominio (ya que es una restricción que pone el navegador) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi de este modo podés deshabilitar la restricción temporalmente y estar 100% seguro que ese es tu problema.

Comment: Ok. Muchas gracias

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por su ayuda!!! ese era el problema. Ahora ya funciona

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque se solucionó entre los comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tienes mal la configuración de la llamada ajax. Te falta establecer el contentType que define el tipo de dato a enviar. Si verificas la llamada a través de Soap UI observa las cabeceras en la petición que se estan enviando.

Prueba añadiendo esto en tu llamada

```
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
```

Comment: Gracias!!!. Pero Intenté, también con eso y no me funciono!!!!

Comment: Hola, la prueba desde tu Soap UI es un GET o un POST. Puede parecer una tontería, pero el verbo HTTP es importante. Saludos

Comment: Es un POST, todos los valores que uso en la llamada los obtuve desde SoapUI. Pero logre capturar el error con el método fail de ajax y el error que retorna es: "Not connect: Verify Network"